# How to access data in JSON response in Angular 8?

Tags: json, angular, web

I am getting data back from a web-server and I am trying to access the data within the JSON object.  I am having some issues with accessing it.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
     "faults": [
      {
        "FaultCodeType": "X",
        "ErrorType": "System",
        "Description": "Response failed for reason 1"
      },
      {
        "FaultCodeType": "Y",
        "ErrorType": "System",
        "Description": "Response failed for reason 2"
      }
     ],
     "responseInfo": {},
     "responseInfo2": {},
     "responseInfo3": {}
}
```

Should I use JSON.parse?

JSON.stringify?

I have the method:

```
loadData(dataPassed) {
  this.angularService.searchWithData(dataPassed).subscribe(
data => {
const fault = data[0];
const fault2 = data[1];
console.log('Data is here = ' + data); // returns the JSON
console.log('Request = ' + JSON.stringify(data)); // shows the JSON
console.log(fault);  // undefined
console.log(fault2); // undefined
  }
}
```

It is not working though, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please tell what is the error you are facing?

Comment: The data when I console.log() is coming back as undefined.  If I console.log the whole response (data) all I get is object Object.

Comment: where are you trying to display data/or running console.log

Comment: I updated the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting undefined because of

```
const fault = data[0];
const fault2 = data[1];
```

as your data is object not array therefore fault[0] does not exists

try

```
const fault = data.faults[0];
const fault2 = data.faults[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

To access `faults`:

`const faults = data.faults;`

Then you can iterate over those `faults`:

```
faults.forEach(f -> {
     console.log('f.FaultCodeType', f.FaultCodeType);
     console.log('f.ErrorType', f.ErrorType);
     console.log('f.Description', f.Description);
})
```

To access `responseInfo`, `responseInfo2` or `responseInfo3`:

```
console.log('data.responseInfo', data.responseInfo);
console.log('data.responseInfo2', data.responseInfo2);
console.log('data.responseInfo3', data.responseInfo3);
```